# Under which conditions solve integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Consider two integrable functions $f$ and $g$, where $f$ is known and $g$ is unknown. The only known things about $g$ is that is $0$ on a compact $[a,b] \subset [0,\infty)$ and it satisfies $\forall s \geq 0$:

$$ \int_{s}^{\infty} g(z) dz = \int_{s}^{\infty} f(z) dz$$

Under which conditions I can conclude for $s \in [a,b]^c \cap [0,\infty)$:

$$ g(s) = \frac{d}{ ds} \int_{s}^{\infty} f(z) dz $$

NB: I am **not** asking under which conditions one can exchange integration and differentiation, since I know which conditions must be fulfilled. I am also not looking for a Leibniz integral rule type of reference. I am really asking under which conditions the above expression is correct and meaningful for $s \in [a,b]^c \cap [0,\infty)$ (and maybe also on $[a,b]$). Is it just by Lebesgue differentiation theorem?